# FB Graph API user search only returns uid, first_name, last_name, username, sex

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Currently experimenting with the FB GRAPH API Explorer Tool for the purpose of searching for (any) users by their first and last names.

Due to this bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331209630309433) I cannot test name searches via the Explorer, so I have instead resorted to investigating what types of data are returned when performing a search.

For this purpose, my test FQL queries are of the following format:

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, sex, website, about_me , activities , email, current_location, birthday_date, books, interests, work, .... {any other field}
FROM user 
WHERE uid in ({list of known/random user ids})
```

I noticed that the query returns values for the fields uid, username, first_name, last_name and sex for all users, but empty/null for any others.

What causes this? Is this because these users are not my 'FB Friends', their permissions are set not to return these fields to the FB G API, or both, or any other reason?

Also, I have noticed that most users have on their public FB website some links/information under the section 'Favorites > Other' - how does this map to the FB G API and how can this be retrieved?

Any advice is appreciated.

John Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/) for rest of the details. Only basic info of the user is available by default.

**UPDATE 1**

Set [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), for setting the permissions.

**UPDATE 2**

See, you cant access the details of the users other than your friends (just basic info will be visible). For the friends, i ran the following query and I got the expected result (after setting the required permissions):

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, sex, website, about_me , activities , email, current_location, birthday_date, books, interests, work
FROM user 
WHERE uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Comment: Thanks. For test purposes I would like to test the permissions in the FB G API Explorer. Under 'Select Permissions > User Data Permissions' I checked all boxes, re-ran my tests but same result - no information/data in my query responses. Are the permissions stored within the access token or are they granted at login-time? Also, what am I missing above in my Explorer tests?